How to render cameras at larger resolutions using cycles?
Using Blender 4.2. I have several cameras with distinct settings. I want to render the scene using Cycles, once for each camera. I can use a single 3D Viewport filling my workspace, and make the camera my active view, to render at < screen resolution (due to UI and window chrome that gets in the way). However, I want to render at (slightly) larger than screen resolution. [This is not a "how do I render a 30k image" question.]
If I choose either View > Viewport Render Image or Render > Render Image I'm shown a completely blank/transparent image. Nothing renders, AFAICT. I find posts online where people say "Oh, yeah, you cannot use Viewport Render Image with Cycles"...but (a) I'm not sure if that's old information (e.g. Blender 2.8) and (b) it does not tell me HOW to render the view through a camera at a fixed size using Cycles.
I'm new to Blender, so I think I might be missing the workflow here. How am I supposed to kick off a render for a camera view using Cycles?

It is true that you cannot use Viewport Render Image when the viewport is in rendered view, only in the other shading modes. For the rest, I do not understand the question. You can set the resolution of the rendered image in the Output Properties, the resolution is not limited to the screen resolution so I'm not sure what you want.

"For the rest, I do not understand the question." The question was ~"if Viewport Render Image and Render Image both produce blank content, what am I supposed to do in order to actually render at the Output resolution". However, I realize I was too hasty: if I invoke Render Image and wait 30s, I start to get progress messages about it gathering the information needed to render. After another minute, the first pass is finally shown. I assumed I was doing something fundamentally wrong since the Viewport approach didn't work.

Render > Render Image (F12) is the correct approach, and does work with Cycles. Depending on scene complexity and computer performance, you may have to wait a long time before you see the first progress message indicating that it's getting ready to render, and an even longer time for the first pass of the Cycles renderer to fill the transparent image. Be patient.
